# Installing VLC on CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, centos-6

I'm using CentOS 6.2, and I tried to install VLC Player using `yum`, but it shows "No package vlc available". I tried below command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install vlc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.5 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.5 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                       | 3.4 MB     01:17     
virtualbox                                               |  951 B     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package vlc available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Is there any rpm package available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.tejasbarot.com/2011/07/25/how-to-install-vlc-player-on-rhel-6-x-centos-6-x-32-bit-64-bit-x86_64-using-script/:

> Perform Following Steps to Install VLC Player on RHEL 6.x / Cent OS
>   6.x on 32 or 64Bit :-
>
> 1) You have to be root to execute this script.
>
> 2) Download RPM ( Auto VLC Redhat Centos6) which I have specially
>   created for VLC Installation Script , You can use RPMs for CentOS 6
>   too.Click on Following link to Download RPM for Your Architecture :-
>
> 32 bit Users click on this link :-
>   http://www.ask4itsolutions.com/RPMs/avrc6-tejas-barot-linux-0.1.0-1.el6.i386.rpm
>
> 64 bit Users click on this link :-
>   http://www.ask4itsolutions.com/RPMs/avrc6-tejas-barot-linux-0.1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
>
> 3) Execute Following Commands as per your Respective architecture :-
>
> For 32 Bit Architecture :-
>
> ```
> rpm -ivh avrc6-tejas-barot-linux-0.1.0-1.el6.i386.rpm
> ```
>
> For 64(X86_64) bit Architecture :-
>
> ```
> rpm -ivh avrc6-tejas-barot-linux-0.1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
> ```
>
> 4) Download VLC Installation Script for RHEL6 and CentOS 6 , Click
>   this link :-
>   http://www.ask4itsolutions.com/RPMs/Scripts/vlc6-installation.sh
>
> 5) Execute following Command where you have downloaded the script.
>   [root@ask4itsolutions ~]# chmod +x vlc6-installation.sh
>
> 6). Now Execute your script by two ways mentioned below
>
> ```
> [root@ask4itsolutions ~]# sh vlc6-installation.sh
> ```
>
> OR
>
> ```
> [root@ask4itsolutions ~]# ./vlc6-installation.sh
> ```
>
> 7) Once you Execute it will ask you 4 Options to Install as per your
>   OS and Architecture and 5th Option for Exit Select Option as per your
>   OS and Architecture
>
> Press (R32) to Install VLC on RHEL 6.x on 32bit Press (R64) to Install
>   VLC on RHEL 6.x on 64bit
>
> Press (C32) to Install VLC on CentOS 6.x on 32bit Press (C64) to
>   Install VLC on CentOS 6.x on 64bit Press (E) to Exit anytime
>
> Please Enter your Selection:
>
> 8) Remember you have to be normal user to run VLC Player, You cannot
>   Run VLC Player as root.

Comment: -1, you copied this from somewhere and didn't even attribute it properly. Please, link to the original source, and copy as little as possible. If you copy something, at least wrap it in blockquotes. Otherwise this is plagiarism. Try to describe the steps in your own words. Ping me when you fixed your post.

Comment: I tried your method and its working fine... thanks a lot

Comment: @suraj You can accept the answer if it helped you. superuser, *please* at least include the link where you got that from.

Comment: Inside that script the original source detail is available.

Answer (score 1):

VLC must not be in your repository. I think you should add [rpmfusion](http://rpmfusion.org) to your repositories. Rpmfusion includes some media software, and plugins for mp3 and mp4, etc....